# What does an ideal correspond to in the internal language of sheaves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Suppose I have a sheaf $\mathcal F$ in some topos $\mathrm{Sh}(\mathcal C)$. Then this becomes the sheaf of rings from algebraic geometry when described as a ring in the internal language of the topos. Whilst in the internal language we were to describe a ring ideal, what would this correspond to externally?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you mean that $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of rings.

What's internally an ideal of $\mathcal{F}$ is externally simply a sheaf of ideals.

In case that the topos in question is the little Zariski topos of a scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ is the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$, you could ask a follow-up question: How can we characterize quasicoherent sheaves of ideals in the internal language?

The answer is that a sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ of ideals is quasicoherent if and only if, from the internal point of view,
$$ \forall f : \mathcal{O}_X.
\forall s : \mathcal{O}_X.
(\text{$f$ invertible} \Rightarrow s \in \mathcal{I}) \Longrightarrow
\bigvee_{n \geq 0} (f^n s \in \mathcal{I}). $$
A proof of this characterization is given in Section 8 of [these notes of mine](https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/notes.pdf), more precisely Corollary 8.5.